# Show Hide Div via jQuery and HTML5 Localstorage

Tags: jquery, html, local-storage

I have found an article https://gist.github.com/jakebresnehan/1983968 for show hide div with html5 localstorage. But when I put on my code it didn't work.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js"></script>
```

My Html

```
<section class="selection-box brandSectionBox">

                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                                <div class="selection-box-title">Brand</div>
                                                <div class="radioStyle clearfix selected brandSection">
                                                    <input name="brandRadio" id="brandRadio" value="desktop" type="radio">
                                                    <label class="selection-box-label col-lg-12">
                                                        <span class="col-lg-6">Desktop </span>
                                                        <span class="col-lg-6 text-right">From $500 </span>
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="radioStyle clearfix brandSection">
                                                    <input name="brandRadio" id="brandRadio" value="laptop" type="radio">
                                                    <label class="selection-box-label col-lg-12">
                                                        <span class="col-lg-6">Laptop </span>
                                                        <span class="col-lg-6 text-right">From $500 </span>
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>


                                            </div>
                                        </div>
</section>


<section class="firstSelected selectedSelectionBox" style="">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                                <div id="selectedfirst" class="selectedItem"></div><div id="changeBox1" class="changeBox"> Change</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
</section>
```

My jQuery code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function($){
    if (Modernizr.localstorage) {

            $(".brandSection").click(function(e) {
              localStorage.setItem('branding',true);
                $(".firstSelected").show();
                $(".brandSectionBox").hide();

            });
            $("#selectedfirst, #changeBox1").click(function(e) {
                    //alert(test);
                    localStorage.setItem('branding',true);
                    localStorage.clear();
                    $(".brandSectionBox").show();
                    $(".firstSelected").hide();
             });

             var is_brand = localStorage.getItem('branding');
             if(is_brand){
                  console.log('localStorage')

                  $(".firstSelected").hide();
             }

             if(!is_brand){
                  console.log('no localStorage');
                  $(".brandSectionBox").show(); 
             }
          } 
      });       
  </script>
```

I'm not sure where I'm doing mistake.

Comment: here you can see https://jsbin.com/sayokihule/edit?html,output

Answer (score 1):

The aim of the https://gist.github.com/jakebresnehan/1983968 is to

**remember the show/hide of the elements when you refresh the page**

In your code before

- `.brandSection` -> click -> `.brandSectionBox` hide + `.firstSelected` show + `branding: true` in localStorage
- `#changeBox1` -> click -> localStorage clear + `.brandSectionBox` show + `.firstSelected` hide

So, when you refresh the page, during the following judge, **they both defaultly show**

- when you have the localStorage `branding` -> `.brandSectionBox` **hide**
- no localStroage -> `.firstSelected` **hide**

After all, your code should be after:

```
$(document).ready(function($){
  if (Modernizr.localstorage) {
    $(".brandSection").click(function(e) {
      localStorage.setItem('branding',true);
      $(".firstSelected").show();
      $(".brandSectionBox").hide();

    });
    $("#selectedfirst, #changeBox1").click(function(e) {
      localStorage.clear();
      $(".brandSectionBox").show();
      $(".firstSelected").hide();
    });

    var is_brand = localStorage.getItem('branding');

    if(is_brand){
      console.log('localStorage')
      $(".brandSectionBox").hide(); 
    }

    if(!is_brand){
      console.log('no localStorage');
      $(".firstSelected").hide();
    }
  }
});
```